# Using datalist on a Ruby on Rails form to display name but pass the id param

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datalist

I have a form where users can add an item to their stock. I would like the form to use datalist. My code is this:

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= form.label :item_id %>
    <%= form.text_field :item_id, list: 'item_id' %>
    <datalist id="item_id">
      <%= options_for_select(current_user.items.map { | item | [item.name, item.id] }) %>
    </datalist>
  </div>
```

But when the user type their search and click on the autocompleted name (for example 'Apple'), the form then displays the id of the item (for example '7'). I would like that instead of changing it to the id, the form only displays the name. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

**This is not a good idea - at all.** Unlike a select a text input is not label/value. What you see is what you get.

So while you could do:

```
<datalist id="item_id">
  <% current_user.items.each do |i| >
  <option><%= i.name %></option>
  <% end %>
</datalist>
```

Which will fill the `item_id` input with the name. But you'll lose the id on the way. Which means that you would either need to lookup the item by name or use some sort of javascript trickery to hamster away that id and replace the input value before the user submits it.

At which point you could actually create a AJAX autocomplete with the same amount of effort thats less of a hacky mess.

Comment: Please don't ask well "how do I do an ajax autocomplete?". The web is riddled with solutions and tutorials. Do your own research.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was looking if there was a way to do it using only Rails (without making it a hacky mess).

Comment: Datalists is cool feature but its not the right tool for this job.